# Declare a reference that extends a class and implement other

Tags: java, android

I'm implementing a game and I have some clases like:

```
GameObject (Abstract)
CircularGameObject
RectangularGameObject
```

They basically store the position (x,y) and the different shapes for checking collisions.

Now I want to implement the classes **Wall** (Rectangular) and **Bomb** (Circular). Both can be enabled or disabled so I declare

```
 public interface Activable {

     public void setEnabled(boolean status);
     public boolean isEnabled();
 }
```

And I have one List for storing a reference to the items that kills the player on the collisions (Walls and Bombs). 
How can I declare an ArrayList of objects that extends GameObject and implements Activable?

I tried declaring a class:

```
 public class ActivableGameObject extends GameObject implements Activable{};
```

but the compiler doesn't allow to assign to that reference a Bomb for example (Because is a CircularGameObject)

Comment: Why not have `Bomb` and `Wall` extend `ActivableGameObject`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Because I'd need bomb to extending ActivableCircularGameObject, wall extending ActivableRectangularGameObject (in order to access their API) and a generic reference for pointing either a wall and a bomb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be be to have:

```
`GameObject implements GameObjectInterface {}`
```

then:

```
`Activable extends GameObjectInterface`
```

That way you can use have make the array use Activable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
Class Bomb extends CircularGameObject implements Activable {

}
```